# Creating a sentence-transformer model in Spark Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, sentence-transformers, huggingface

I used a pre-trained model from the sentence transformer library to check the similarity between two sentences. Now I need this particular model to be implemented using spark mllib. Any Suggestions? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

https://www.sbert.net/
https://spark.apache.org/mllib/

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried with a library called Spark NLP - https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/. I'm not sur if you can export model from sentence-transformer to make them work with Spark NLP but you should give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

One approach that I found to work is to use a [Pandas UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) that encodes the text and returns the embedding. This embedding column could then be used with MLlib.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, StringType
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

# import sbert model
model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# sentences to encode
sentences = [
    "This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence",
    "Sentences are passed as a list of string.",
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
]

# create spark df with sentences
data = spark.createDataFrame(sentences, StringType(), ["sentences"])
data.show()

# create a pandas udf that will encode the text and return an array of doubles
@F.pandas_udf(returnType=ArrayType(DoubleType()))
def encode(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(model.encode(x).tolist())

# apply udf and show 
data.withColumn("embedding", encode("value")).show()
```

output

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|This framework ge...|
|Sentences are pas...|
|The quick brown f...|
+--------------------+

+--------------------+--------------------+
|               value|           embedding|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|This framework ge...|[-0.0137173617258...|
|Sentences are pas...|[0.05645250156521...|
|The quick brown f...|[0.04393352568149...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Ok @David... I've done this with a lot more trouble before. My big question for you is this: how do you do this with a GPU and batching? :D We tried on PySpark / Databricks and man, it was hard. I don't know if we ever got it working.

Comment: For Databricks all I had to do is run the above code on a GPU cluster/runtime. As for batch size there are two "batches". One is how many rows the Pandas UDF processes.  which you can set via `spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch` (default 10,000). Then the SBERT library has a `batch_size` (default 32) parameter that you can adjust in the `.encode()`.

Comment: Ok, that would be amazing. Thanks!